# goto token usage causes syntax error in java

Tags: java, class, package, minecraft, bukkit

I get an error with this code:

```
ERROR: if ((goto == 791) || (!w.equals("Sugar"))) {
```

and error is:

```
1. ERROR 1,LINE 190: Syntax error on token "goto", invalid Expression
2. ERROR 2,LINE 231: Type mismatch: cannot convert from World to String
3. ERROR 3,LINE 238: The operator && is undefined for the argument type(s)int,boolean
```

what do I do?

Code: http://pastebin.com/vH4y2gTW
sorry, couldn't post code here because the format doesn't show numbered lines..

Comment: `goto` is a reserved keyword in Java. You can't use it as a variable. It's used in flow control.

Comment: So what do I replace it with?

Comment: With a name that is not reserved? Ah, sorry, how should *we* know what a reasonable name for that variable is in your code? And for the record: please study the  [help]; for example learn about providing a [mcve] when asking questions here. And we dont need numbered lines, it is just fine to simply put a comment into the line that gives the problem.

Comment: You know that you have to **declare** variables first? And as said: turn to the help center. We do not see it as our job here to help you fix all your wrong syntax one by one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ERROR 1,LINE 190: Syntax error on token "goto", invalid Expression
```

You can't call a variable *goto*, that is a *reserved* word in Java.

```
ERROR 2,LINE 231: Type mismatch: cannot convert from World to String
```

You have a variable that contains a *World*; and you want to turn that into a string (by casting, or passing in the wrong place). Try

```
worldObject.toString()
```

instead. But you know, programming is not about "stopping the compiler from complaining". It is about "doing the correct thing". So maybe you can just use that call to create a string representation of that World; but maybe you are doing something really wrong; and should be doing something else completely.

```
ERROR 3,LINE 238: The operator && is undefined for the argument type(s)int,boolean
```

Simple: you cant do

```
intVar && booleanVar
```

Simply because && is a the *logical* AND operator; and that only works with **two** boolean arguments. In Java, you can't use numbers for AND, OR, and so on!

The **real answer** here: these are absolut java basics. You should really not need to turn to other people in order to translate those already clear, human readable compiler error messages.

My personal recommendation here: spent some time studying such java basics. There is no point in trying to write code for Minecraft when you think you need to turn to us for such subtleties. In other words: learn to crawl before you try to run.

Comment: Thanks man! I did what you said and it worked, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the quick accept. But as said: my **main** point is: you better step back for a while to read, learn, and practice. Otherwise, you will run from one error to the next; and worse: even when your programs will *start* at some point; chances are high that they will just crash, or worse: cause damage.